# How to get equal spacing between Buttons on Grid Layout?

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am new to designing a layout. My app has a startup screen with a grid Layout consisting of 11 Buttons. I want to make somewhat like this

[image]

But ended up getting this

[image]

Just want to know how can i give equal spacing from every side of screen and between buttons.

Here's my XML code

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
    >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:columnCount="2"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button

            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"

            android:id="@+id/th1"

            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 2"

            android:id="@+id/th2"
            />


        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 3"
            android:id="@+id/th3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"

            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 4"
            android:id="@+id/th4"

            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 5"
            android:id="@+id/th5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 6"
            android:id="@+id/th6"
            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 7"
            android:id="@+id/th7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 8"
            android:id="@+id/th8"
            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 9"
            android:id="@+id/th9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 10"
            android:id="@+id/th10"
            />
        <Button
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_townhall"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="Town Hall 11"
            android:id="@+id/th11"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            />

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You could add additional rows & columns between each button.

Comment: The layout provided at the top probably has logic to check at runtime the environment it is running in, I.e. adjusts correctly for all screen dimensions. Your XML layout is very static, you may get it right for one screen, but not for another. I'd suggest using a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager with our own RecyclerView.ItemDecoration

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
```

to each button.